# Using Multiple JavaScript Scripts on an ASPX Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use multiple JavaScript files on my website.
The first block of code below works fine.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Then, I add the below scripts:

```
  <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The first block above still works as expected, but the second block does not. While debugging, I removed the first block, & then the second block works as expected.

Below is the code which requires the first block:

```
 <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("ImageName","~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' title='<%#Eval("Description") %>' rel="lightbox[Brussels]" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
                                                </a>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                                        </asp:DataList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

And here is the code which requires the second block:

```
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li class="active"><a href="#service-one" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tree"></i> Group One</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-two" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Group Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-three" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-support"></i> Group Three Three</a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service-four" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Group Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="service-one">
                    <h4>Group One</h4>
                    <p>Paragraph 1 of group one</p>
                    <p>Paragraph 2 of group one</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-two">
                    <h4>Group Two</h4>
                    <p>Paragraph 1 of group two</p>
                    <p>Paragraph 2 of group two</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-three">
                    <h4>Group Three</h4>
                    <p>Paragraph 1 of group three</p>
                    <p>Paragraph 2 of group three</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="service-four">
                    <h4>Group Four</h4>
                   <p>Paragraph 1 of group four</p>
                    <p>Paragraph 2 of group four</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Regarding the 2nd block of HTML, when you click on an unordered list item, the relevant paragraph is meant to appear:

[image: groupTab]

It does appear, however the previous tab is removed for some reason:
[image: grouTabTwo]

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? I'd guess that the libraries are interfering with each other. Also, are you sure you want to load *all* those libraries?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, there are no errors appearing in the console. Also, I have posted the code which requires the different libraries. I commented each script out to see if any of them were required to provide the functionality I need, but unfortunately they appear to all be needed

Comment: They may all be needed at the moment, but loading 3 separate frameworks and 2 libraries that rely on them is a lot. If possible I'd highly suggest you refactor your code to only use one framework.

Comment: Does nothing need initialising? Sometimes there is methods you need to call to initialise some libraries. Try reading the documentation for your libraries if there is no error in the console window

Comment: Are you sure you need prototype.js and scriptaculous.js? scriptaculous.js hasn't been updated since 2010; prototype since 2015. The first block only shows the need for lightbox.js, which is an independent library. Also, you might look at the order in which the libraries are loaded; try loading jQuery, then bootstrap, then lightbox.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid unneeded calls for JS files, my main JS files using the jQuery load scripts: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

I use this for calling plugins when i need.